# HBase and HDFS data delimiters?

Tags: hadoop, hbase, hdfs, sqoop

I have **HBase** data exported to **HDFS**. I would like to **Sqoop** export **HDFS** to **MySQL**. But while using Sqoop export, it requires me to provide how HDFS data is delimited. How to check what delimiters are in a HBase table or in a HDFS data?

**Edit 1**: I exported HBase data to HDFS using 
**bin/hadoop jar /path/to/hbase-0.20.3.jar export your_table /export/your_table**

Answer (score 2):

As far as HBase is concerned there is no question of any delimiter. You data is stored in columns in an HBase table. And to know the delimiter of an HDFS file you can :

- Use **bin/hadoop fs -cat /path/to/file**
- Browse the file through the **HDFS WebUI** and find that by looking at its content.

But this mainly depends on how you have exported your data. **For example**, if you have used the HBase export utility then your data will be dumped into HDFS as a sequence file.

Comment: Hi Tariq! Please see my updated question with 'Edit 1:' which explains how I exported HBase to HDFS

Comment: As I have specified above **export** utility exports the data as a sequence file. See this for more on Sequence files : http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/SequenceFile